# How can I specify a local jar file as a dependency in Play! Framework 1.x

Tags: maven, playframework, dependencies, playframework-1.x

I have a jar file copied in the lib directory

I'd like to run "play deps --sync" without this jar being deleted..

I've already looked at [depency file documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/dependency) but couldn't figure out how to do it

any idea?

**-- edit**

I've just found the answer: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/b54e4e25ae49161b

Gonna google around a bit more before asking here

Answer (score 25, accepted):

just like the answer in google groups said, I could achieve it with the following dependencies.yml file

for library /jar/DateHelper-1.0.jar

```
require:
    - play -> crud
    - provided -> DateHelper 1.0 
repositories: 
    - provided: 
        type:       local 
        artifact:   "${application.path}/jar/[module]-[revision].jar" 
        contains: 
            - provided -> *
```

(You need to create the jar dir and put your jar files in it)

so, according to the ${xxxx} it seems like dependecies.yml file is processed like a template... just like happens with the routes file

Comment: I've been told in the google list that dependencies file just processes simple expressions, like ${application.path}, and not every groovy expression like a template

Comment: You can't use the lib directory for that. I updated your answer to match the advice in the Groups discussion.

Comment: There is more complete documentation available at: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/dependency#Localrepositories

Comment: in spanish too: http://playdoces.appspot.com/documentation/latest/dependency#Repositorioslocales

Comment: This works but you need to run, play dependencies PROJECTNAME followed by eclipsify after adding this to dependencies.yml.