# Play Framework: Add a dependency that points to a directory of local jar files

Tags: java, dependencies, playframework

Is it possible to add a dependency to the dependencies.yml that points to a directory?

For example, using pseudo yml for the dependencies.yml, I want to do something like this:

```
require:
    - mycooldirectory

repositories:
    - mycooldirectory:
        type: local
        artifact: "${application.path}/jars/mycooldirectory/*.jar"
        contains: 
            - mycooldirectory -> *
```

In my make-believe-world, the above would include the mycooldirectory as a classpath folder and use any jars found in that directory.

I'm just making stuff up, but I hope that kind of explains what I want to do.  I know you can put jars in the /lib directory but any jars unspecified by the dependencies.yml will get wiped when doing a `play dependencies --sync`.  I also know you can specify single jars by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184427/how-can-i-specify-a-local-jar-file-as-a-dependency-in-play-framework).  However, I was just wondering whether you can do something similar but reference a whole directory full of jars?

**Edit:** I have a sort of workaround which works is by creating a Play module structure for mycooldirectory (i.e. have a lib directory under that directory) and put all the jars in that lib directory.   And then in the dependencies.yml, do this:

```
require:
    - mycooldirectory -> mycooldirectory

repositories:
   - provided:    
       type:       local
       artifact:   "${application.path}/jars/[module]"
       contains:  
         - mycooldirectory
```

Though I was wondering whether there was a cleaner way of doing this without having to make a pretend module and just reference a new directory to have additional jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This workaround is similar to yours, but it should work without a `/lib` directory. I haven't tested it, but it was on the mailing list and got positive feedback there.

```
require:
  - play
  - play -> googleclosure 1.2
  - provided -> mylib 1.0

repositories:
  - provided:
      type:       local
      artifact:   "${application.path}/jar/[module]-[revision].jar"
      contains:
        - provided -> *
```

Mailing list thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/tU5OJa5JFhs/discussion

Comment: Yes I have seen that but as far as I can tell, that just refers to one jar at a time (and not a directory full of jars).  Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't the above just say "I want to include the jar mylib-1.0.jar" from the "jar" directory as a dependency?".  Whereas I want to say "add all jars from some directory without having to specify jars one by one"

Comment: You are right. `- provided -> mylib 1.0` only adds one jar, but you can use that line more often, but I guess thats not what you want. Have you tried something like `- provided -> * *`. Otherwise try to post your question to the mailing list.

Comment: Perhaps obvious, but I wanted to point out that `provided` can be whatever you want (for example, your organization name).  Also, if you have a "1.0-SNAPSHOT" version or whatever, leave off the "-SNAPSHOT" part in the `require` section or Play will complain.